# Using generic open graph objects and actions, and the publish_actions permission?

Tags: permissions, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to use the beta open graph API to publish about a user playing songs in my app. Besides the "normal" Open Graph docs, I found these:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

Unfortunately I am not able to add generic actions like 'music.listens' or generic objects like 'music.song' to my app in the dev app. In order to get the publish_actions permission, however, I seem to be obliged to add at least an action, an object and a preview aggregation. If I don't, the auth dialog won't ask for the publish_actions permission.

When I do all this, I am able to get the publish_actions permission, but still I cannot publish a user listening to a song.

I get a 500 error 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unknown error has occurred."' when I try to publish by POSTing a request to this url:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens?song=http://open.spotify.com/track/34uKquOrQLgzBsUbFTkMTc&access_token=[...]

Is the publish_action permission bound to actions and objects that I have created within the namespace of my app? If so, how should I go about when I want to perform generic actions on generic objects? Or could this just be that I cannot use the spotify song for testing?

Hope someone can help.
Erwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in music actions and objects are currently only available to the music launch partners.

In the meantime, please create your own custom song objects and listen actions.

publish_actions is the permissions used for all publishing of actions, custom and built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the info Simon! Quick answer too. Now that's developer love :) Is the availability of these actions and objects for everyone besides the launch partners on the roadmap?

Comment: TBD. But at the very least you will be able to use a custom action against a built-in object (song) - we have a bug with that at the moment.