# Opengraph and music.listen

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Trying several time to use the music.listen action and ending up trying to create our own listen action and song object.
Some posts suggested that music.listen and songs built in actions and object were for now only available to launch partners.

Can anybody tell if this is true and if yes how we can become a launch partner for the music opengraph ?

Thanks.

known urls : 
[Using generic open graph objects and actions, and the publish_actions permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869338/using-generic-open-graph-objects-and-actions-and-the-publish-actions-permission)

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7602579/opengraph-music-music-listens-returns-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

music.listen is an action only available to selected partners at present. The music.listen action and the Song object are not available for general use.

Facebook are monitoring the ecosystem and will decide at a later date if music.listen is available beyond the existing launch partners.

In the meantime, we suggest you create your own custom 'Play' action and your own custom Song object - custom actions called 'listen' won't currently be approved by Facebook.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Is there a way to get in contact with facebook about this ?

Comment: I have the same question and rejection. We want to use listen for listening to public radio content, who can I talk to at facebook?

Comment: @AndrewKuklewicz - build a custom listen action.

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for replying.  I did create an action, and it got rejected: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/119755508101509/opengraph/action_type/185368498206876  I fixed the other issues, but don't know who to contact about getting access to 'listen'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's true, but either way it sounds like you will need to have your companies business development team contact Facebook to see if there's still time to become a launch partner.

Comment: Thanks DMCS. Does anybody have contact information for facebook opengraph. Because support requests about music opengraph seem to stay unanswered.

Comment: Not I, but your business dev team will know how to make contact.

Comment: Business development groups is not a software development group.  Business development are people who reach out to other companies in order to strike deals, partnerships, and connections with